# top navigation list item margin bug

Tags: css

I am making a website's top navigation. There is a margin bug with the menu.

I have defined `margin / padding : 0` for list items as well as `display: inline-block`.

See the demo: http://tinkerbin.com/495Qb956

Basically I want to remove that left/right margin from the list items, and know why this margin is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default **display:inline-block** take margin from left. Write like this:

```
.top-right ul {
    background:black;
    height:43px;
    font-size:0;
}
.top-right ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        font-size:13px;
}
```

Check this http://tinkerbin.com/YWeV7osy

Comment: This solution works because of the `font-size: 0` rule making the *spaces* between li items to zero pixels, it has nothing to do with margin-left on li items.

Comment: @Jeroen i know that. That's why i write it. I explain in my way.That's doesn't mean you downvote someone. There solutions also like this letter-spacing & word-spacing

Comment: I downvoted because I think the answer is wrong. Specifically the first sentence "by default display: inline-block take margin from left" seems incorrect imho. The li items with display: inline-block *have no margin-left* (it was already set to 0 by the OP). In addition, setting font-sizes to fix this problem feels like a hack to get the desired effect, and I think there are [better solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12172644/419956).

Answer (score 0):

That room you're seeing are spaces between the blocks. If you remove all white-space between the `</li>` and `<li>` you'll see the space disappear. Basically an inline-block will behave like a word in a sentence, and any white-space between two of those blocks will be folded into 1 space char.

One solution is to use floats to make the blocks stick together:

```
li { float: left; }
```

You might need to `clear` the elements that come after such floating elements.